# Explanations on Scipy Gaussian Mixture score computation

Tags: python, scoring-algorithm

I'm looking at Scipy's way of calculating the score of a sample in a Gaussain mixture model, and there is something I don't get.

I'm taking as reference [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/gaussian-mixture-model/) [definition](https://brilliant.org/wiki/multivariate-normal-distribution/):
$$
\begin{align}
p(\vec{x}) &= \sum_{i=1}^K\phi_i \mathcal{N}(\vec{x} \;|\; \vec{\mu}_i, \Sigma_i)\\
\mathcal{N}(\vec{x} \;|\; \vec{\mu}_i, \Sigma_i) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^K|\Sigma_i|}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu}_i)^\mathrm{T}{\Sigma_i}^{-1}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu}_i)\right)\\
\sum_{i=1}^K\phi_i &= 1
\end{align}
$$
where $K$ is the number of components, $\mu_k$ and $\Sigma_k$ are the mean and the covariance matrix of the $k^{th}$ component, and $\phi_k$ is the weight of the  $k^{th}$ component in the mixture.

Scipy computes $\log(p(\vec{x}))$ in the function `score_samples`, in files [base.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/mixture/base.py) and [gaussian_mixture.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/mixture/gaussian_mixture.py):

```
class BaseMixture[...]:
[...]
    def score_samples(self, X):
        """Compute the weighted log probabilities for each sample."""
        [...]
        return logsumexp(self._estimate_weighted_log_prob(X), axis=1)

    def _estimate_weighted_log_prob(self, X):
        """Estimate the weighted log-probabilities, log P(X | Z) + log weights."""
        [...]
        return self._estimate_log_prob(X) + self._estimate_log_weights()
```

Ok, so here they just simplify future calculations by:
$$
\log(p(\vec{x})) = \log\left(\sum_{i=1}^K\exp(\log(\phi_i) + log(\mathcal{N_i}))\right)
$$
`_estimate_log_weights` just returns what its name says:

```
class GaussianMixture(BaseMixture):
    def _estimate_log_weights(self):
        return np.log(self.weights_)
```

My issue is with `_estimate_log_prob`:

```
    def _estimate_log_prob(self, X):
        return _estimate_log_gaussian_prob(X, self.means_, 
            self.precisions_cholesky_, self.covariance_type)
```

where `self.means_` is $\mu$ et `self.precisions_cholesky_` is "the Cholesky decomposition of the precision matrices of each mixture component. The  precision matrix is the inverse of the  covariance matrix", $\Sigma$ in the original definition.

If we look at the definition of `_estimate_log_gaussian_prob`, we have:

```
    def _estimate_log_gaussian_prob(X, means, precisions_chol, covariance_type):
        """Estimate the log Gaussian probability."""            
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape
        n_components, _ = means.shape

        # det(precision_chol) is half of det(precision)
        log_det = _compute_log_det_cholesky(
            precisions_chol, covariance_type, n_features)
        [...]
        log_prob = np.empty((n_samples, n_components))
        for k, (mu, prec_chol) in enumerate(zip(means, precisions_chol)):
            y = np.dot(X, prec_chol) - np.dot(mu, prec_chol)
            log_prob[:, k] = np.sum(np.square(y), axis=1)
        [...]
    return -.5 * (n_features * np.log(2 * np.pi) + log_prob) + log_det
```

This is supposed to compute:
$$
\log(\mathcal{N}(\vec{x} \;|\; \vec{\mu}_i, \Sigma_i)) = \log(\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^K|\Sigma_i|}}) + \left(-\frac{1}{2}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu}_i)^\mathrm{T}{\Sigma_i}^{-1}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu}_i)\right)\\
= - 0.5 K \log(2\pi)-0.5 \log(|\Sigma_i|) + \left(-\frac{1}{2}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu}_i)^\mathrm{T}{\Sigma_i}^{-1}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu}_i)\right)
$$

At this point, I have two questions:

- Aren't `log_prob` and `log_det` inverted? (Why isn't it `return -.5 * (n_features * np.log(2 * np.pi) + log_det) + log_prob`?)
- Is `log_prob` really calculating $-\frac{1}{2}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu}_i)^\mathrm{T}{\Sigma_i}^{-1}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu}_i)$ ? How?

Comment: Well, the computation do not seems to be too hard to code. I dont know Scipy unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have stated in the question the log probability of the multivariate gaussian is as follows. I'll take a single component to simplify notation.
$$
 \log{\mathcal{N}(x | \mu, \Sigma)} = -\frac{1}{2}K\log{2\pi} - \frac{1}{2}\log{|\Sigma|} - \frac{1}{2} (x - \mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu) \tag{1}
$$

The Scipy algorithm is using the Cholesky decomposition of the precision matrices. The precision is the inverse of the covariance, i.e.,
$$
  \Lambda = \Sigma^{-1}
$$
Let $L$ denote the Cholesky decomposition of a particular precision matrix, so that,
$$
  \Lambda= LL^T
$$

**Computing the log_prob**

Starting from the Mahalanobis term in Equation (1),
$$
\begin{align}
   ( x - \mu )^T \Sigma^{-1} (x - \mu ) =&  ( x - \mu )^T \Lambda (x - \mu ) \\
=& ( x - \mu )^T LL^T (x - \mu ) \\
=&  \|L^T (x - \mu )\|^2
\end{align}
$$

The algorithm first computes $ y = L^T (x - \mu_i )$ using the dot function, and then takes the norm squared, i.e. $log\_prob = \|y\|^2$. It then needs to multiply by a factor of $-\frac{1}{2}$, which happens in the return statement.

**Computing the log_det**

Starting from the log determinant term in equation (1),
$$
\begin{align}
  -\frac{1}{2}\log{|\Sigma|} =& -\frac{1}{2} \log{|\Lambda^{-1}|} \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\log{|\Lambda|} \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\log{|LL^T|} \\
=& \log{|L|}
\end{align}
$$

In the return statement, $log\_det = \det{L}$, and so there is no need to multiply by $-\frac{1}{2}$.

**The whole computation**

In summary, the final computation in Scipy is,
$$
 \log{\mathcal{N}(x | \mu, \Sigma)} = -\frac{1}{2} \left( K\log{2\pi} + \|L^T(x - \mu)\|^2 \right) +\log{|L|}
$$

Comment: Thanks, great explanation!